# Is there a way to automatically add data by contraints to table B when I add data to table A

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been doing some JavaEE for Web application lately. I'm currently doing the database for my assignment.

Let's take the Customer Account for example

So, in my assignment, I wanted to have a register function which allow normal user to create account.

In this, I have Customer Info (Name, Phone number, registration date,... ) separated from Account info (username, password).

It's mean when a user submit a registration form. In my DAO layer (notice that I'm using MVC). I have 2 different queries to execute - one to add the data to the `[Customer]` table, and another to add the data to the `[Account Details]` table. And the general table between them is `[CustomerAcoount]` table.

The question: is there a way to automatically add data to `[CustomerAccount]` table when I add data to `[Customer]` and `[AcoountDetails]` table?

[image: My Database Diagram Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what's called a `trigger` to automatically call a query on `Insert`, `Update` or `Delete`. Find more info about them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

You can create one for your tables like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertCustomerAccount
ON Customer  
AFTER INSERT
AS -- Your Query to insert into CustomerAccount
GO
```

You can access the data you've just inserted via the table `inserted`.

So your insert query could look something like this:

```
Insert into CustomerAccount(yourcolumns)
select * from inserted
```

This will then always execute this insert query if you insert something in the `Customer` table. You can use this concept to insert data across multiple tables "at the same time".

Comment: It works for me bro. Now, Instead of writing manual Insert Querry string in DAO layer I can use this to optimize my code
Thankyou